# Read 64 bit integer string from file

Tags: c++, parsing, 64-bit, integer

We have a file that has a 64 bit integer as a string in it. How do we scanf() or otherwise parse this numeric string into an unsigned 64 bit integer type in C++ ?

We are aware of things like %lld etc., but a lot of ways to do this parse seem to break compiles under different compilers and stdlibs. The code should compile under gcc and the Microsoft C++ compiler (of course full compliance with standards would be a plus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC has long long, as will compilers for C++0x. MSVC++ doesn't (yet), but does have its __int64 you can use.

```
#if (__cplusplus > 199711L) || defined(__GNUG__)
    typedef unsigned long long uint_64_t;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__) 
    typedef unsigned __int64 uint_64_t;
#else
#error "Please define uint_64_t"
#endif

uint_64_t foo;

std::fstream fstm( "file.txt" );
fstm >> foo;
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use uint64_t from stdint.h. It's a C99 standard, not C++, but it's in GCC and you can easily find VC++ versions online and bung them in your project. Same goes for J. Random platform in future, and if we're lucky it'll be in C++0x.

Comment: It is in C++0x. Though (u)int64_t is actually optional, one can safely assume it will be available for PCs. Otherwise, one can use uint_least64_t or uint_fast64_t.

Answer (score 4):

Alnitak recommends `strtoull()`, but it seems it's not [available in Win32](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/d69a6afe-6558-4913-afb0-616f00805229/) environments. The linked-to forum thread recommends either of `_strtoui64()`, `_wcstoui64()` and `_tcstoui64()` as replacements. Perhaps this is "on the edge" of stuff that can't really be done with a single portable function call, and you might need to implement different code paths for different platforms. Or, I guess, write your own ASCII-to-64-bit converter, it's not rocket science.

Answer (score 3):

Or use the typesafety of istream...

```
  using namespace std;

  // construct a number -- generate test data
  long long llOut = 0x1000000000000000;
  stringstream sout;
  // write the number
  sout << llOut;
  string snumber = sout.str();
  // construct an istream containing a number
  stringstream sin( snumber );

  // read the number -- the crucial bit
  long long llIn(0);
  sin >> llIn;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::fstream fstm( "file.txt" );
__int64 foo;
fstm >> foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `scanf()`, tokenize your input separately and then use `strtoull()` or similar.

Comment: Is strtoull() supported on Windows natively?

Comment: You can quite easily make your own.

Comment: To be fair, I did say "or similar" :)